# Enable VoiceOver ine only one app?

Tags: ios, music.app, voiceover

My kid likes to listen to music on her iPad, but she can't read yet (she's working on it) so she has to play each song for a few seconds to find the song to which she wants to listen. Is there a way to enable VoiceOver for just the Music app? Enabling it for the entire device is annoying. Or is there an alternate way to play music that will speak the song titles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't enable VoiceOver for just one app, but you can easily turn VoiceOver on and off.

**Method 1(Siri):** Just launch Siri(by pressing and holding the home button), and say "Turn on Voice Over", and and Siri will reply(no reading necessary). You can also turn Voice Over off, by saying "Turn of Voice Over" when you leave the app.

[image: siri screenshot]

**Method 2(Acessibility Shortcut):** Go to Settings > General > Accessibility > Accessibility Shortcut and tap "VoiceOver". Now whenever you triple-click the home button, it will enable voice over, and when you triple click it again, it will disable VoiceOver.

[image: accessibility shortcut]

Answer (score 3):

My six year old son is always asking "What song is this?" when we play music, and I got tired of having to go read the titles for songs I didn't know (common when we're listening to soundtracks, etc.). So I ended up figuring a way to *almost* announce *only* the songs (currently on macOS 12/Monterey so this should work for anything above that).

1. In VoiceOver utility, go under Verbosity and set it to 'Low', then click the 'Announcements' tab & un-check everything except 'Automatically speak text in dialog boxes'. This will keep the chatter to a minimum.

[image: VoiceOver Utility screen 1: Verbosity/Speech]

[image: VoiceOver Utility screen 2:Verbosity/Announcements]

2. Next, go under 'Speech' on the left side and hit 'Mute speech'. This will mute everything in general so you don't have to hear every single thing that's happening. We'll make an exception for Music in the next step.

[image: VoiceOver utility screen 3: Speech/Voices]

3. Select 'Activities' in the left side, click the '+' to add a new activity, and then call it 'Music' (or whatever app you're setting). Then you can change the defaults for that app- in this case I checked 'Speech' and made sure that 'Mute speech' was unchecked (if you don't see this, hit the little v/^ toggle button on the right side. Then open the 'Use this activity for:' menu and select the apps you want to enable it for (in my case, Music and Sonos).

[image: VoiceOver Utility screen 4: Activities]

Caveat: it does seem that the app selected needs to be the active app, or VoiceOver won't read the notification (i.e. the song title), so if you're in another app it won't narrate. But for my use case, I can start the music, leave the app open, and go do something else, and the computer will faithfully announce the song titles (I even have those going through the system speaker while the music plays through the Sonos speakers so we don't have to hear the computer voice in the rest of the house).

Note: I noticed OP was for iOS devices, but it appears you can do the same, just note that the preferences screens will look a bit different.